# Marionette CollectionView with jQuery Mobile Listview

Tags: jquery-mobile, marionette, jquery-mobile-listview

I currently used Backbone.Marionette with jQuery Mobile to generate a jQuery Mobile Listview from a Marionette CollectionView.

Before, I would simply use:

```
this.$el.parent().enhanceWithin();
```

in the onShow method of the CollectionView to enhance the generated HTML with jQuery Mobile.

But now, I implemented asynchronous loading. That means, I display the view (show it and enhance it) before there are any list items in the view. I display an empty view instead (emptyView property of the CollectionView).

When my collection has finished fetching, I assign it to my view. But these items do not get enhanced by jQuery Mobile.

I tried to use the same code as above ( `this.$el.parent().enhanceWithin();` ) in the onAfterItemAdded-Event of the CollectionView, but it doesn't work.

Now I tried

```
this.$el.listview().listview("refresh")
```

This works, but I heard this function will be / is deprecated. Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: no, `.listview()` widget and its' functions wont be deprecated. you could try `this.$el.closest("[data-role=page]").enhanceWithin();` to enhance all items dynamically added. **Edit:** are you adding `data-role="listview"` attribute to `ul`? it wont work without it if you use `.enhanceWithin()` but works with `.listview()`.

Comment: I already use enhanceWithin with the data-role = listview attribute added for when the view is first shown (to get the filter bar to show up). If the function listview() is not going to be deprecated, it's fine.

Comment: Only _Nested List-view_ is deprecated but not _List-view_ widget itself http://jquerymobile.com/changelog/1.4.0/#listview